# ASP.NET MVC Unit Test Project Entity Framework error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing

I got the following error when using an EF class in my Unit Test project for ASP.NET MVC.

**The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'**

Many posts propose as solution adding the correct assemblie line to the web.config:

```
<assemblies>
   <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</assemblies>
```

however, I'm getting this error in **MySample.Tests** project, so there is no web.config.

I'm posting this question and answer as a reference in case someone else get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to "System.Data.Entity" dll at References folder of your Unit Test project.